# Isolation level and DIRT READ SQL SERVER 2005 (advanced question)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, locking, isolation

I will describe my problem for an easier explanation:

I have a table and my soft is accessing it (update, insert) using transaction.

The problem is that I want to enable DIRT READ in this table. But I cant use with (nolock) in my sql statements because I cant change the soft source. So I was thinking in enable dirty read in the sql process that begin the transaction.

It seens that the command "SET ISOLATION LEVEL ..." and "WITH (NOLOCK)" are executed in the statements that do access the locked table... that's what I'm try to avoid. I want to enable dirt read in the statement that begin the transaction...

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really want to allow dirty reads? Or do you want to allow reads that are not blocked by the insert/update?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no point in changing the isolation level of your **writes**, like insert or update. Writes always take exclusive locks on anything they update, period. What you can do is to change the isolation level of your **reads**, your SELECT statements.
2. Dirty reads are **never** necessary. 99% of the times they are the indication  of bad schema and query design that results in end-to-end scans that are guaranteed to block on locked rows. The solution is to properly change the schema, add necessary indexes to avoid scans. This does not require source changes.
3. For the rare cases when contention is indeed unavoidable and the schema is correctly designed, the answer is never to enable dirty reads, but to turn to [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095.aspx):

   `ALTER DATABASE ... SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;`
    `ALTER DATABASE ... SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;`

For the few deployments where the overhead of row-versioning introduced by snapshot isolation is visible, they have professionals at their disposal to alleviate the problem.

Comment: the problem of READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT its that I can't execute-it because "There must be no other open connection in the database until ALTER DATABASE is complete.", so I'm trying a few alternatives... 

While my soft its processing data, a lot of updates and insert are executed. And that process can only stop when its completly finished. But I cant lock my table for such long time that's why I want to do the dirty read...

Comment: The statements in #3 only have to executed once, not every time! Can't you wait until everybody is off the server?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE ... WITH ROLLBACK AFTER N SECONDS;` or  `.. WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`, it will kick out (interrupt connections) the existing users. You should do this after making sure you don't disrupt activity, during off-peak hours, and announce the affected users of the incoming outage.

Comment: Thank you Remus and everybody, this solution solve my problem! thanks a lot!